# how uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I can't uninstall Microsoft Enterprise 2015.Its trial version has been expired and I want to uninstall it. Is there any other way to uninstall it?

Comment: Doesn't "Control Panel -> Programs and Features ->find program in list -> right click -> Uninstall" work?

Comment: @ChrisF so there isn't any uninstall for this one

Answer (score 0):

Create another admin account and Log In with new created account and delete the folder, if it is not in Program List.

Comment: it's in the program list